# Leading Zeroes on Char column are Not being Persisted (Python + SQL)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

The following function assigns a unique key (derived from a SQL table) to files so they will comply with a naming convention

```
def assign(fList, p):
    for i in fList:
        p += 1
        lz = leadingZero(p)
        oldName = fileDirPath + fr'\{i}'
        if lz == 1:
            newName = fileDirPath + r'<prefix value>' + str(p) + '<suffix value>'
            print(newName)
        else:
            newName = fileDirPath + r'<prefix value>' + str(p) + '<suffix value>'
            print(newName)
    if leadingZero(p) == 1:
        sqlConnectWrite('0' + str(p))
    else:
        sqlConnectWrite(str(p))
```

In order to properly comply with the naming convention the key 'p' must always be 5 digits, and have a leading zero if the key value is less than 10,000. The following function sets an integer "lz" equal to 1 if a leading zero needs to be added, and 0 if it does not need to be added.

```
def leadingZero(num):
    lz = 0
    if num < 10000:
        lz = 1
    elif num >= 10000:
        lz = 0
    else:
        logging.error("Leading Zero Boolean: something has gone terribly wrong")
        print("ERROR: Invalid Integer Passed, please email <email>")
    return lz
```

The first function (`def assign`) then passes the last key assigned to the following function so that it can update the SQL table that stores the most recent key value, so we can keep track of what key values have been assigned

```
def sqlConnectWrite(pFinal):

    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=<server>;'
                              'Database=<database>;'
                              r'UID=<user>;'
                              'PWD=<pass>;'
                              'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("SQL Connection Successful!")
        print("Running Query....")
        print('SQL WRITE OPERATION INITIATED')
        print(pFinal)
        cursor.execute(f'UPDATE <SQL TABLE> SET [Last Used Number]  = {str(pFinal)}')
        conn.commit()
    except pyodbc.Error:
        logging.exception('SQL: Exception thrown in write process')
    finally:
        print('SQL Operations Successful')
        conn.close()
```

Despite my best efforts, when I update the SQL table, the p value seems to persistently revert back to an integer, which removes the leading zero (shown below). The SQL table value is an `nchar(5)` data type but I cannot seem to find a way to update the table such that the leading zero is retained. I cannot determine why this is the case.

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04z5B.png)

Comment: You should simplify your question asking for the leading zeros problem instead of giving not very useful information to make easy to understand the problem

Comment: You are specifying the value as an integer in the ` UPDATE` statement.  To keep it as a string, you must quote the value, as in `... = '{pFinal:05d}')`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you clarify, I'm not quite understanding what you mean

Comment: @FranArenas Should I change the title? I'm not sure how to explain what I'm trying to accomplish simply, or why it isn't working, as the issue produces no traceback or exceptions

Comment: @ankill I think something like "Leading zeros on char column are not being persisted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String values in an SQL expression need to be surrounded with single quotes.  Otherwise, they are interpreted as integers, and integers don't have leading zeros.

```
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE <SQL TABLE> SET [Last Used Number]  = '{pFinal:05d}'")
```

Quoting is vitally important in an SQL context.  Even better would be to get in the habit of allowing your database connector to do the substitution:

```
        cursor.execute("UPDATE <SQL TABLE> SET [Last Used Number] = ?", (f"{pFinal:05d}",))
```

Assuming SQL Server uses ? for substitution.  Some databases use %s.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering!

This makes some more sense, but I can't actually put it in implementation. I've tried rearranging things, and using both ```?``` and ```%s``` but both return ```ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'``` 

The server is a MS SQL Server I'm not sure if that is useful information. I don't know much of the server's more intimate details because I work alongside a Database Admin and I don't end up getting access to much of the server's back end

Comment: If you have already converted `pFinal` to a string, then just skip the `:05d` part.  I thought maybe you were sending it as an intetger.

Comment: thank you so much, your solution solved my issue perfectly, I was really stumped and it was holding up progress on this project. I really appreciate your help